# PCF - Stream logs to multiple servers

Tags: kibana, splunk, cloud-foundry

I am running Docker image of my `spring-boot` application in PCF. It is streaming logs to 2 different servers; I have configured 2 User Defined services with syslog drain to Splunk and the other is to Kibana. Both of the services are bound to the `spring-boot` app.

Would this cause any performance issue that streaming logs to multiple log servers from the same application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would this cause any performance issue that streaming logs to multiple log servers from the same application?

Will it cause a performance impact to your application?  no.

Your application logs to STDOUT/STDERR and Diego reads this information and sends it off through Loggregator. Loggregator is then responsible for sending the messages off to your log drains, however many you configure.

As far as the platform is concerned, it has a finite amount of resources and each log drain you configure is going to require additional resources. Fortunately, your platform operators can monitor the resource usage and scale up Loggregator to meet their application developer's needs, so it really shouldn't matter if you configure one or two.

Hope that helps!

Comment: One quick question.. The user has said that he has deployed in PCF as a docker ... Checking if docker containers will also be orchestrated by Diego ??

Comment: It doesn't matter. The behavior above is not specific to buildpack apps or docker apps. All logs from apps go out the same way.

Comment: No no ... My question is not related to Log drains ... am asking you on a separate note .. Does docker containers are also managed by Diego in CF ?? I thought Diego manages only Garden Containers...

Comment: If you're asking different, unrelated questions, please open a new question. That allows you to set the context so people know what you are asking.

Comment: @Arun To answer your question, there are no "docker" or "garden" containers. The Linux kernel is what provides the primitives to make a "container" (which isn't really a thing, it's just a process that has some things done to isolate it). Docker is mostly a way of easily constructing what to put in the container. Diego supports Docker images because it's able to take your files from a docker image & run them. If you want to push app code or a docker image, either way Diego knows how to deploy & run your stuff.

Comment: That’s pretty much I want to know... Thank you so much Sir